# Htc desire 628 bootloop in recovery mode after flashing TWRP

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, twrp, htc-desire

I flashed my phone with twrp, tried to enter recovery mode through the bootloader, but now it's on endless boot, how can I fix that?

In download mode:

```
hTC download mode

*** UNLOCKED ***
htc_v36bml_uhl PVT S-ON
LK-1.01.0000
RADIO-UNKNOWN
OpenDSP-UNKNOWN
OS-1.16.401.1
Aug  2 2016, 19:11:15(788931)

[options here]

Detecting smart card...
Reboot to ftm mode failed due to NOT_FIND_SMART_IO
```

In bootloader:

```
*** Software status: Modified ***
*** Unlocked ***
HTC_V36BML 128 SHIP S-ON

CID-HTC__A07
LK-1.01.0000
OS-1.16.401.1
```

When i select to boot to recovery mode, appears message, which says 'This build is for development purposes only', after that's boot freezes. OEM and bootloader unlocked, USB debugging enabled

Comment: `'This build is for development purposes only` is shown by the bootloader. It is simply a notification that the bootloader has been unlocked and thus the system may be modified/compromised. This warning is important for people you buy a used phone.

Comment: flash working twrp ([1](https://gitlab.com/HosteBin/androidlover5842_1/-/tree/master/htc/v36bml_dugl_00400), [2](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=5862345805528061470)) and reboot straightforward into recovery right after flashing, otherwise your custom recovery will be replaced with stock recovery

Comment: @alecxs, tried to boot right after flashing, same thing:

```Sending 'recovery' (11924 KB)                      OKAY [  0.462s]
Writing 'recovery'                                 (bootloader) HOSD CL#788931
(bootloader) start@1
(bootloader) recovery@100%
(bootloader) Update partition OK
(bootloader) end@Done
OKAY [  2.585s]
Finished. Total time: 3.067s
Sending 'boot.img' (11924 KB)                      OKAY [  1.477s]
Booting      <---- on this step boot freezes```

Comment: there is also downgrade protection S-ON must be S-OFF. try revolutionary, rumrunner or firewater